# How do I update the state of a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have two buttons in my react App.js and when clicked I want my current state(list) to change to descending order according to which button i press(order by date or order by upvotes). My articles.js have the code that display the list of articles. But I'm having a hard time showing the list sorted after clicking the button tag found on my App.js which is the parent component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


function Articles({articles}) {
    const [list, setList] = useState(articles)
    
    return (
        <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Upvotes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
              {list.map((a, i) => 
                    <tr data-testid="article" key={i}>
                    <td data-testid="article-title">{a.title}</td>
                    <td data-testid="article-upvotes">{a.upvotes}</td>
                    <td data-testid="article-date">{a.date}</td>
                    </tr>
              )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Articles;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'h8k-components';

import Articles from './components/Articles';

const title = "Sorting Articles";


function App({articles}) {
    //set article to state then pass
    const handleUpvotes = () => {
        articles.sort((a, b) => a.upvotes - b.upvotes).reverse()
        console.log(articles)
    }
    const handleDates = () => {
        return
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h8k-navbar header={title}></h8k-navbar>
            <div className="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center my-20 navigation">
                <label className="form-hint mb-0 text-uppercase font-weight-light">Sort By</label>
                <button data-testid="most-upvoted-link" className="small" onClick={handleUpvotes}>Most Upvoted</button>
                <button data-testid="most-recent-link" className="small" onClick={handleDates}>Most Recent</button>
            </div>
            <Articles articles={articles}/>
        </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Remove `const [list, setList] = useState(articles)` and use `articles.map((a, i) =>` instead. Your `handleUpvotes` is mutating articles, you should probably pass that function from the component that provides `articles` and set local state with a new list: `setArticles=>(articles=>[...articles].sort((a, b)...`

Comment: Where does `articles` come from in `function App({articles}) {`?

Answer (score 2):

The `useState` should be in the `App`

```
const [list, setList] = useState(articles)

    //set article to state then pass
    const handleUpvotes = () => {
        articles.sort((a, b) => a.upvotes - b.upvotes).reverse()
        setList(articles)
    }
```

Comment: Is mutating articles, maybe `setList(list=>[...list].sort((a, b)...` and pass list to Articles: `<Articles articles={list}/>`

Comment: @HMR I think the setList([...articles]) should work

Comment: handleUpvotes should probably be in a useCallback so `setList([...articles].sort)` needlessly creates a dependency to articles.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Effect Hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
useEffect(() => {
   // articles was changed
}, [articles])
```

Comment: Array.prototype.sort does not change articles, it mutates it so effect is only called on mount.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It should work if you listen for changes in [JSON.stringify(articles)] but that might not be very sustainable.

Comment: Sort should set state state with a sorted copy: `setState(state=>[...state].sort`

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you are facing is that a misunderstanding of the React reactivity model, now lets take a look at this line

```
articles.sort((a, b) => a.upvotes - b.upvotes).reverse()
```

here you are successfully updating the array, but think about it. if React updated the UI whenever a variables inside the component updates that would be ineffective and problematic.

so in order to notify React about what has changed and it needs to update the UI, whenever you change a variable and you need the UI to update, you use `useState` from react.

and another point is that in your `Article` component you are expecting props, and calling `useState` at the time.

so moving the `useState` into the `App` component dose the work

```
const [list, setList] = useState(articles)

    const handleUpvotes = () => {
        articles.sort((a, b) => a.upvotes - b.upvotes).reverse()
        setList(articles)
    }
```

Comment: Setting state with mutated array will not re render the component: `setList(list=>[...list].sort` will do the trick but OP code has some other problems. Where does articles come from in `function App({articles}) {` and why would you copy it to local state? I think the articles and sort should be in context or passed from the component that has it in it's initial state but then you need to prop drill.

Comment: you're right ```setList(list=>[...list].sort``` worked over the code written above, but why? Both codes are basically the same. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where articles come from and if they need to be used in multiple components so I'll put them in context, that way you can use it anywhere in your application.

```js
const ArticleContext = React.createContext();
const ArticleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = React.useState([
    { title: '1', upvotes: 1, date: 1 },
    { title: '3', upvotes: 3, date: 3 },
    { title: '2', upvotes: 2, date: 2 },
    { title: '4', upvotes: 4, date: 4 },
  ]);
  const sortDirection = React.useRef(-1);
  const sortByUpvotes = React.useCallback(() => {
    //toggle sort direction
    sortDirection.current = sortDirection.current * -1;
    setArticles((articles) =>
      [...articles].sort(
        (a, b) =>
          (a.upvotes - b.upvotes) * sortDirection.current
      )
    );
  }, [setArticles]);
  return (
    <ArticleContext.Provider
      value={{
        articles,
        sortByUpvotes,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ArticleContext.Provider>
  );
};

function Articles() {
  const { articles } = React.useContext(ArticleContext);
  return (
    <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Upvotes</th>
            <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {articles.map((a, i) => (
            <tr data-testid="article" key={i}>
              <td data-testid="article-title">{a.title}</td>
              <td data-testid="article-upvotes">
                {a.upvotes}
              </td>
              <td data-testid="article-date">{a.date}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const { sortByUpvotes } = React.useContext(
    ArticleContext
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center my-20 navigation">
        <label className="form-hint mb-0 text-uppercase font-weight-light">
          Sort By
        </label>
        <button
          data-testid="most-upvoted-link"
          className="small"
          onClick={sortByUpvotes}
        >
          Most Upvoted
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* no need to pass articles, they are in context */}
      <Articles />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ArticleProvider>
    <App />
  </ArticleProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The next example shows how to sort using multiple fields:

```js
const ArticleContext = React.createContext();
const ArticleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = React.useState([
    { title: '1', upvotes: 1, date: 3 },
    { title: '3', upvotes: 3, date: 3 },
    { title: '2', upvotes: 2, date: 4 },
    { title: '4', upvotes: 4, date: 2 },
  ]);
  const sortDirection = React.useRef([-1, -1]);
  const sortPriority = React.useRef([0, 1]);
  const sortFunctions = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      (a, b) =>
        (a.upvotes - b.upvotes) * sortDirection.current[0],
      (a, b) =>
        (a.date - b.date) * sortDirection.current[1],
    ],
    []
  );
  const sort = React.useCallback(() => {
    setArticles((articles) =>
      [...articles].sort((a, b) =>
        sortPriority.current.reduce(
          (result, fnIndex) =>
            result === 0
              ? sortFunctions[fnIndex](a, b)
              : result,
          0
        )
      )
    );
  }, [sortFunctions]);
  const setDirectionAndPriority = (num) => {
    if (sortPriority.current[0] === num) {
      sortDirection.current[num] =
        sortDirection.current[num] * -1;
    }
    sortPriority.current = [
      num,
      ...sortPriority.current.filter((n) => n !== num),
    ];
  };
  const sortByUpvotes = () => {
    setDirectionAndPriority(0);
    sort();
  };
  const sortByDate = () => {
    setDirectionAndPriority(1);
    sort();
  };
  return (
    <ArticleContext.Provider
      value={{
        articles,
        sortByUpvotes,
        sortByDate,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ArticleContext.Provider>
  );
};

function Articles() {
  const { articles } = React.useContext(ArticleContext);
  return (
    <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Upvotes</th>
            <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {articles.map((a, i) => (
            <tr data-testid="article" key={i}>
              <td data-testid="article-title">{a.title}</td>
              <td data-testid="article-upvotes">
                {a.upvotes}
              </td>
              <td data-testid="article-date">{a.date}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const { sortByUpvotes, sortByDate } = React.useContext(
    ArticleContext
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center my-20 navigation">
        <label className="form-hint mb-0 text-uppercase font-weight-light">
          Sort By
        </label>
        <button
          data-testid="most-upvoted-link"
          className="small"
          onClick={sortByUpvotes}
        >
          Most Upvoted
        </button>
        <button
          data-testid="most-recent-link"
          className="small"
          onClick={sortByDate}
        >
          Most Recent
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* no need to pass articles, they are in context */}
      <Articles />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ArticleProvider>
    <App />
  </ArticleProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```